# AreValid or IsValid? Naming bools that refer to multiple items

Tags: naming-conventions

This probably sounds like an obvious one for experienced coders but for me who codes only occasionally AreValid seems to get lost in the code. So I am tempted to use IsValid, as long as the name is in plural form e.g. AreUserInputsValid but what do the naming conventions say?

Answer (score 0):

I think in the most languages it is preferred to use the non-plural notation. So you can define it like `IsUserInputValid` (Notice Input instead of Inputs). 
Input can be considered as a 'group' and therefore can be named as with `Is`. This goes the same for array/List implementation `IsArrayValid`, still it can has more than 1 entries, yet you will 'group' it by the name of array.